# I got following error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here's Main Activity code and **logcat file** and I am using Android studio last version. If anyone knows, please help !;

```
public class MainActivity extends WifiActivity implements OnTouchListener{

    private ImageButton mSpeakButton;
    private TextView mDisplay;
    private DisplayAsyncTask mDisplayTask;
    private ImageView rxView;
    private ImageView txView;

    private static String mSendTempFile;
    private static String mPlayTempFile;
    private IntentFilter CIntentFilter;
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
    private MediaPlayer   mPlayer = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(this.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        CIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        CIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        CIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        CIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        CIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);


        WifiP2pManager mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(this.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);

        Channel mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
        mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Discovery Initiated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                // Code for when the discovery initiation fails goes here.
                // Alert the user that something went wrong.
            }
        });
        mSpeakButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.speakButton);
        mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.screenText);
        rxView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rxView);
        txView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.txView);

        mSpeakButton.setOnTouchListener(this);

        mSendTempFile = getFilesDir() + "/send_temp.3gp";
        mPlayTempFile = getFilesDir() + "/play_temp.3gp";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mDisplayTask = new DisplayAsyncTask();
        mDisplayTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        mDisplayTask.stop();

        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }

        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    private void bufToFile(byte[] buf, String fname) {
        BufferedOutputStream bos;
        try {
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(fname)));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        try {
            bos.write(buf);
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void showData(byte[] data) {
        rxView.setImageResource(R.drawable.led_red_on);
        Toast.makeText(this, "showData = " + data.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        bufToFile(data, mPlayTempFile);

        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(mPlayTempFile);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
            mPlayer.setLooping(false);
            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                    mPlayer = null;
                    rxView.setImageResource(R.drawable.led_red_off);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        txView.setImageResource(R.drawable.led_green_on);
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mSendTempFile);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mRecorder.start();
    }

    private byte[] fileToBuf(String fname) {
        InputStream in;
        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fname));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100 * 1024];

        try {
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            bos.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        txView.setImageResource(R.drawable.led_green_off);
        try {
            mRecorder.stop();
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        byte[] data = fileToBuf(mSendTempFile);
        publishData(data);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startRecording();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            stopRecording();
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private class DisplayAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private boolean stop = false;

        public void stop() {
            stop = true;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            while(!stop) {
                publishProgress();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            ConnectionState state = MainActivity.this.getState();

            if(state.mConnected) {
                sb.append("CONNECTED\n");
                if(state.mWeAreGroupOwner) {
                    sb.append("GO\n");
                } else {
                    sb.append("CL\n");
                }
            } else {
                sb.append("NOT CONNECTED\n");
            }

            mDisplay.setText(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

and the error logcat file

```
wifidirecttalkie, PID: 14950
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.senniksoft.wifidirecttalkie/com.senniksoft.wifidirecttalkie.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: instance name or service type cannot be empty
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: instance name or service type cannot be empty
            at android.net.wifi.p2p.nsd.WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo.newInstance(WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo.java:94)
            at com.senniksoft.wifidirecttalkie.WifiActivity.setupService(WifiActivity.java:90)
            at com.senniksoft.wifidirecttalkie.WifiActivity.onCreate(WifiActivity.java:112)
            at com.senniksoft.wifidirecttalkie.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5293)
```

And WifiActivity codes

```js
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pConfig;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.DnsSdServiceResponseListener;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.DnsSdTxtRecordListener;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.nsd.WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.nsd.WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

import com.senniksoft.wifidirecttalkie.ConnectionState.Buddy;

public abstract class WifiActivity extends Activity {

 private WifiP2pManager mManager;
 private Channel mChannel;
 private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
 private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;
 private TextView mTextView;
 private TextView mStatTextView;
 private WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo mServiceInfo;
 private WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest mServiceRequest;
 private MessageDeduplicator mDeduplicator = new MessageDeduplicator();
 
 private DiscoveryBGThread mDiscoveryTask;
 private StatusDisplayBGThread mStatusUpdateTask;
 private ConnectionBGThread mConnectionTask;
 private ServerBGThread mServerTask;
 
 private final static String LOGTAG = "WIFI_P2P_VS";
 private final String SERVICE_NAME = "_walkietalkie._tcp";
 
 public final static int SERVER_PORT = 42634;
 private TextView mConnStatTextView;
 private RegisterClientBGThread mRegisterTask;
 private ReceivedMessageShower mMessageShowTask;
 
 /**
  * Get mac address of our wifi adapter, notice that this can
  * differ some bits from our Wifi P2P adapter address. 
  * @return
  */
 private String getMacAddress() {
  WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(
                Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInf = wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();
        return wifiInf.getMacAddress();
 }
 
 /**
  * Setup for service discovery/Bonjour
  */
 private void setupService() {
  //  Create a string map containing information about your service.
        Map<String, String> record = new HashMap<String, String>();
        record.put("listenport", String.valueOf(SERVER_PORT));
        record.put("device_name", Helpers.getDeviceName());

        // Service information.  Pass it an instance name, service type
        // _protocol._transportlayer , and the map containing
        // information other devices will want once they connect to this one.
        mServiceInfo =
                WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo.newInstance(getMacAddress(), SERVICE_NAME, record);
 }
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
     mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
     mReceiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this);
     mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
     mStatTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statTextView);
     mConnStatTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connStatTextView);
     
     // add intent filter for getting Wifi Framework intents
     mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
     mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
     mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
     mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
     mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);
     
     setupService();
     setupServiceListeners();
     setupDebugButtons();
 }
 
 /**
  * Buttons to switch betw phone and debug view
  */
 private void setupDebugButtons() {
  Button debugButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.debugButton);
  debugButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {((ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher)).showNext();}
  });
  
  debugButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.debugButton2);
  debugButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {((ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher)).showNext();}
  });
 }
 
 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     
     // init a new connection state on every app resume
     state = new ConnectionState(getMacAddress());
     
     // register our broadcast receiver to listen for events
     registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
     // register our bonjour service in the net
     mManager.addLocalService(mChannel, mServiceInfo, null);
     
     // listen for bonojour services of other peers
     mServiceRequest = WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest.newInstance();
        mManager.addServiceRequest(mChannel, mServiceRequest, null);
        
        // start all background tasks
        mDiscoveryTask = new DiscoveryBGThread();
        mStatusUpdateTask = new StatusDisplayBGThread();
        mConnectionTask = new ConnectionBGThread();
        mServerTask = new ServerBGThread();
        mRegisterTask = new RegisterClientBGThread();
        mMessageShowTask = new ReceivedMessageShower();
     mDiscoveryTask.start();
     mStatusUpdateTask.start();
     mConnectionTask.start();
     mServerTask.start();
     mRegisterTask.start();
     mMessageShowTask.start();
 }
 
 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
     
     // stop the background tasks
     mDiscoveryTask.setStop();
     mStatusUpdateTask.setStop();
     mConnectionTask.setStop();
     mServerTask.setStop();
     mRegisterTask.setStop();
     mMessageShowTask.setStop();
     
     // unregister eveything
     mManager.removeLocalService(mChannel, mServiceInfo, null);
     mManager.removeServiceRequest(mChannel, mServiceRequest, null);
     
     mManager.cancelConnect(mChannel, null);
     mManager.removeGroup(mChannel, null);
 }



 /**
  * Class to send data from the child
  * class (MainActivity)
  * @param data
  */
 protected void publishData(byte[] data) {
  if(state.mWeAreGroupOwner) {
   broadcastData(data);
  } else {
   sendData(data);
  }
 }
 

 protected abstract void showData(byte[] data);
 

 private void broadcastData(byte[] data) {
  if(!state.mWeAreGroupOwner) {
   return;
  }
  Log.d(LOGTAG, "BROADCAST");
  byte[] msg = NetworkProtocol.composeMessage(NetworkProtocol.CMD_SEND_DATA, data);
  for(InetSocketAddress a: state.getClientAddresses()) {
   Log.d(LOGTAG, "CLIENT BROADCAST TO IP="+a);
   sendMessageToAddr(msg, a);
  }
 }
 

 private void sendData(byte[] data) {
  if(state.mWeAreGroupOwner) {
   return;
  }
  Log.d(LOGTAG, "SEND");
  byte[] msg = NetworkProtocol.composeMessage(NetworkProtocol.CMD_SEND_DATA, data);
  mDeduplicator.addMessage(data);
  sendMessageToAddr(msg, state.getGroupOwnerConnectionInfos());
 }
 
 private void dataReceived(byte[] data) {
  if(!mDeduplicator.messageIsNew(data)) {
   return;
  }
  
  // put into queue
  messagesToProcess.offer(data);
  
  // rebroadcast immediately
  if(state.mWeAreGroupOwner) {
   broadcastData(data);
  }
 }
 
 private BlockingQueue<byte[]> messagesToProcess = new ArrayBlockingQueue<byte []>(100);
 
 /**
  * This thread looks on the queue which contains received messages.
  * Every time we got one, we call showData() with the data in
  * the queue. This is to serialize receive events which also
  * might arrive concurrently.
  * @author joni
  *
  */
 private class ReceivedMessageShower extends Thread {
  private boolean stop = false;

  public void setStop() {
   stop = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
   while(!stop) {
    try {
     final byte[] data = messagesToProcess.poll(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
     if(data != null) {
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
        showData(data);
       }
      });
     }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
     try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
     } catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
    }
   }
  }
 }
 

 private class ServerConnectionThread extends Thread {

  private final Socket client;
  
  public ServerConnectionThread(Socket client) {
   this.client = client;
  }
  
  public void run() {
   try {
    InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
    
    String cmd = NetworkProtocol.getMessageType(in);
    if(cmd != null && cmd.equals(NetworkProtocol.CMD_REGISTER_CLIENT)) {
     String mac = NetworkProtocol.getMacAddress(in);
     state.updateClientIp(mac, client.getInetAddress());
    }
    if(cmd != null && cmd.equals(NetworkProtocol.CMD_SEND_DATA)) {
     final byte[] data = NetworkProtocol.getData(in);
     
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
       WifiActivity.this.dataReceived(data);
      }
     });
    }
    
             in.close();
             client.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {}
  }
 }
 
 /**
  * Async method to send a raw byte message to an ip address
  * @param msg
  * @param addr
  */
 private void sendMessageToAddr(final byte[] msg, final InetSocketAddress addr) {
  if(addr == null)
   return;
  
  new Thread() {
   public void run() {
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    try {
     socket.bind(null);
     socket.connect(addr, 5000);
     
     socket.getOutputStream().write(msg);
     socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }.start();
 }
 
 /**
  * Out of simplicity, every node runs this thread all the time.
  * It tries to communicate to the group owner our mac address
  * (and he can get over the socket also our ip address).
  * @author joni
  *
  */
 private class RegisterClientBGThread extends Thread {
  private boolean stop = false;

  public void setStop() {
   stop = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
   while(!stop) {
    tryToRegister();
    try {
     Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
   }
  }
  
  private void tryToRegister() {
   if(!state.mConnected || state.mWeAreGroupOwner) {
    return;
   }
    
   byte[] msg = NetworkProtocol.composeMessage(NetworkProtocol.CMD_REGISTER_CLIENT, getMacAddress());
   sendMessageToAddr(msg, state.getGroupOwnerConnectionInfos());
     }
 }
 

 private class ServerBGThread extends Thread {
  private ServerSocket serverSocket;
  
  public void setStop() {
   try {
    serverSocket.close();
   } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
  
     @Override
     public void run() {
         try {
             serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);
             
             try {
              while(true) {
               Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
               ServerConnectionThread conn = WifiActivity.this.new ServerConnectionThread(client);
               conn.start();
              }
             } catch (SocketException e) {
              // our serverSocket got killed, exit
              e.printStackTrace();
             }

         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }
 
 private ConnectionState state;
 
 public ConnectionState getState() {
  return state;
 }

 /**
  * Called in onResume, sets up service discovery listeners
  */
 private void setupServiceListeners() {
     DnsSdTxtRecordListener txtListener = new DnsSdTxtRecordListener() {
   @Override
   /**
    * Yay we got a device which published its name
    */
   public void onDnsSdTxtRecordAvailable(String domain, Map<String, String> record, WifiP2pDevice device) {
    state.updateStatus(device, record.get("device_name"));

    try {
     state.updateStatus(device,
       Integer.parseInt(record.get("listenport")));
    } catch(Exception e) {}
   }
     };
     
     DnsSdServiceResponseListener servListener = new DnsSdServiceResponseListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDnsSdServiceAvailable(String instanceName, String registrationType, WifiP2pDevice device) {
          if(ConnectionState.macAddressAlmostEqual(device.deviceAddress, getMacAddress())) {
           return;
          }
          
          Buddy b = state.getBuddy(device.deviceAddress);
   
    b.device = device;
    
       if(registrationType.startsWith(SERVICE_NAME)) {
        b.rightService = true;
       }
         }
     };

     mManager.setDnsSdResponseListeners(mChannel, servListener, txtListener);
 }
 
 /**
  * Every 10sec, make a rediscovery of peers so we see new ones.
  * The results are not received here but in the broadcast receiver.
  * @author joni
  *
  */
 private class DiscoveryBGThread extends Thread {
  private boolean stop = false;
  
  public void setStop() {
   stop = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void run(){
   while(!stop) {
    mManager.discoverServices(mChannel, null);
    mManager.requestConnectionInfo(mChannel, null);
    
    try {
     Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
   }
  }
 }
 
 
 /**
  * Display debug info
  * @author joni
  *
  */
 private class StatusDisplayBGThread extends Thread {
  private boolean stop = false;
  
  public void setStop() {
   stop = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
   while(!stop) {
    updateStatus();
    try {
     Thread.sleep(1 * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
   }
  }
  
  private void updateStatus() {
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
     mTextView.setText(state.buddiesToString());
     mStatTextView.setText(state.toString());
    }
   });
   
     }
 }
 
 /**
  * Connect as soon as possible, reconnect, set state etc.
  * @author joni
  *
  */
 private class ConnectionBGThread extends Thread {
  private boolean stop = false;

  public void setStop() {
   stop = true;
  }
This is main Wifi operation codes that does wifi peer to peer connections between mobile phones
  @Override
  public void run() {
   while(!stop) {
    manageConnection();
    try {
     Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
   }
  }
 }
 
 private void manageConnection() {
  final StringBuilder connState = new StringBuilder();

  if(state.connected()) {
   connState.append("CONNECTED\n");
   // search for buddies which have to be invited
   for(Buddy b: state.findSingleBuddies()) {
    connState.append("INVITE: " + b + "\n");
    WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
    config.deviceAddress = b.device.deviceAddress;

    mManager.connect(mChannel, config, null);
   }
  } else {
   connState.append("NOT CONNECTED\n");
   if(state.haveGroupOwner()) {
    connState.append("E GROUP OWNER, WAIT 10 sec\n");
    try {
     Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
   } else {
    connState.append("NO GROUP OWNER\n");
    // try to connect to the first buddy
    Buddy b = state.findBuddyToConnect();
    
    if(b != null) {
     connState.append("CONNECT TO: " + b + "\n");
     WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
     config.deviceAddress = b.device.deviceAddress;
     
     mManager.connect(mChannel, config, null);
    } else {
     connState.append("NO BUDDY TO CONNECT TO\n");
    }
   }
  }
  
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    mConnStatTextView.setText(connState.toString());
   }
  });
 }
}
```

This is main Wifi operation codes that does wifi peer to peer connections between mobile phones

Comment: What is the code around this line:  com.senniksoft.wifidirecttalkie.WifiActivity.setupService(WifiActivity.java:90) ?

Comment: This code at 90: mServiceInfo =
                WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo.newInstance(getMacAddress(), SERVICE_NAME, record);
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static method `newInstance` of `WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo` you are calling in your WifiActivity seems to be wrong. Here is the method signature:

```
public static WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo newInstance (String instanceName, String serviceType, Map<String, String> txtMap)
(Added in API level 16)
```

The problem is that (based on your stacktrace) instanceName or serviceType is empty. Make sure when calling `WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo.newInstance(getMacAddress(), SERVICE_NAME, record);` that `getMacAddress()` AND `SERVICE_NAME` are not null.

Comment: Thank you for answering and I double checked again wifi Activity and could not found anything related to null. Actually I did not understand, the app was complately running and then suddenly throw this error and it still persisting, it drives me crazy :D

Comment: Chances are your MAC address is null.  Maybe you turned off wifi?  At the very least, log those values before you try to use them, so you will be able to see which is at fault in the logcat of the *next* crash.

Comment: Agreed. Follow +Chris comments: log your macAddress() before executing the static method that causes the error.

Comment: Dear Chris Stratton, well done, I am appraciated well :) Thank you very much. The problem solved !

Comment: Dear Quanturium, Thank you very much, I log the mac adress and turn on wifi and problem solved